# Nhibernate : QueryOver equivalent for ICriteria's SetComment?

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, comments, queryover

Is is possible to add a comment to generated by queryover query in Visual Studio's output?
Previously when we were using ICriteria, there was simple SetComment method and we could set the query name so it was much easier to find specific query in output full of long (almost the same) queries. If it is possible we would prefere to add such comments without converting query to ICriteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way of doinf it, but you can try with:

```
QueryOver<Entity>()
.Where(...
.UnderlyingCriteria.SetComment("....")
```

Comment: Yes it can be done like that but as I said, I don't want to convert to Criteria cause my method returns IQueryOver which is parameter for another method.

Comment: @Kostrzak in the codebase of the 3.2 version there is no a direct way to do with QueryOver. Let me say that by calling UnderlyingCriteria you are not "converting" but just using what queryover uses behind the scenes. Id the problem is that it break the fluent api, just put it at the end.

Comment: I think it is the only solution for now. I will probably use  Session to store Query's name and add it using setComment just before calling .List<T>();